# Systematic solution to a repeating underfull \hbox problem

Tags: typography

I have a repeating problem with the `underfull \hbox` that occurs at least a few dozen times in the document. The reason is that in the `itemize` environment I provide the data that contains the thermal conductivity with the horribly long unit `W/(m K)` (`siunitx` used). Only on one page below are there seven instances of this problem.

[image]

What should I do to solve this problem?

- make `itemise` `raggedright`
- line break between number and unit
- something else
- just ignore

(I know that according to Knuth's rules I should put `~` after conductivity, but I ignored the rule for long units to alleviate the problem elsewhere.  I hope this is not another blunder on my side.)

**PS** I have recently been warned that I am using poor typographic/page design, although I have consulted several semi-professional designers. Could you **please** suggest a service/person that will make a reliable assessment of the typographic/page design and give me a list of suggestions/improvements that I can then implement myself?

Comment: well it looks horrible, so I wouldn't ignore it (how do you manage to get it? It isn't the default). Try the various options and decide which looks better, if you make a line break I would try after the 'and' perhaps add a suitable article: `and \\  a terminal conductivity`.

Comment: since the items are so short, I'd use raggedright (but I have no formal design training)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What do you mean, "how do you manage to get it"?  I just used `itemize` and put in the text I need.  If I make a line break, this will effectively make it `raggedright` if I understand right...?

Comment: by default tex wouldn't create an underfull box and spread the spaces like this, you would get an overfull hbox instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Honestly, no idea.  I use `KOMA` and `MinionPro`, maybe that has something to with it.

Comment: no, koma wouldn't do that too. It is something in your document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\sloppy` possibly:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have `\tolerance 1414 \hbadness 1414 \emergencystretch 1.5em \hfuzz 0.4pt \widowpenalty=10000 \vfuzz \hfuzz \raggedbottom`.  I picked that from `stackexchange` years ago when I had some problem.  Should I remove it since I use `microtype`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but the question is why only for the lists? perhaps they are in a box?

Comment: You can try to remove that, yes, or at least use more moderate values.  But the P3.8 list will be difficult to get good breaks in. (It looks like there is even extra space inbetween the m in mm in 50m and 150mm.) (You should have given a complete MWE in the first place.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess just because they are short paragraphs just a little over one line so there are not many options

Comment: @mickep After removing those I get 30 more `\overfull`s...  It is a document of 200 pages and MWE would be really long and complex with dozens of packages loaded.

Comment: @Pygmalion that's expected. Now you have shown code rather than just an image your question may be simplified to "I am allowing excessive white space to avoid overfull boxes, but I get excessive white space. What are my options?"

Comment: @Pygmalion you could (and should) make a MWE with no packages loaded at all (or maybe just `[T1]{fontenc}`)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I must admit that after removing all this salad, they most (but not all) convert to `\overfull`s.  But I get 30+ other `\overfull`s elsewhere.

Comment: The only general solutions to avoiding overfull boxes are to set the document ragged, or set it justified but allow arbitrarily bad white space stretching. Anything else will require specific tweaks depending on the text at hand.  That is not a latex issue just a nature of the problem, if the text is `a b` even with microtype you can not distort the letters to fill the line so you must set ragged and set a lot of space after `b` or justify but set a lot of space between `a` and `b`  it is your document, you have to choose.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This was exactly my question.  Should I leave it as it is, allowing too much space between the words, or go ragged... or if there is by any chance a third acceptable option (like line break within quantity).  From the point of view of proper typography.

Comment: as I say, if you know those particular lists just have 1 or 2 line items, I'd set them ragged (just as bibliographies are often set ragged) as there is so little flexibility in line breaking for a 2 line paragraph